# Rails Boostrap table-striped can't add additional background to striped rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I wanted to have a striped table as already provided by twitter-bootstrap and then additionally add a background image to only certain rows. The image is to repeat across the whole row. The problem is that the background image does not show up in the striped rows. I then added the image to a div inside each td of the row. This worked almost perfectly because the image is small so that you could still see the shading in the striped rows and therefore could still tell the row was striped. The problem with this approach was that the image would get cut off at the end of the cell and then restart in the next cell and so it looked very choppy. If you're curious what the image was it is just an arrow I designed(though the image could change in the future). Therefore I was trying to get an arrow going across the entire row repeatedly.

**Is there a way to use both the striped table and add the background image to the row? If not, is there an easy way to do striped table manually?**

This is what I tried and works for the image but I had to use just `table` and not `table-striped` and therefore loss my alternating striped rows:

```
<table class="table">
    <% @sessions.each do |session| %>
        <% if session.status == 0 %>
           <% classname = "active"  %>
        <% else %>
           <% classname = "noactive" %>
        <% end %>

        <tr class= <%= classname %> >
            <td><%= link_to session.name, "session_path"%></td>
            <td><%= link_to session.user, edit_user_path(session.user)%></td>
            <td><%= link_to "Details", details_path, :class => "btn btn-mini" %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

This is with trying to add at the td level instead:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <% @sessions.each do |session| %>
        <% if session.status == 0 %>
           <% classname = "active"  %>
        <% else %>
           <% classname = "noactive" %>
        <% end %>

        <tr >
            <td><div class= <%= classname %>><%= link_to session.name, "session_path"%></div></td>
            <td><div class= <%= classname %>><%= link_to session.user, edit_user_path(session.user)%></div></td>
            <td><div class= <%= classname %>><%= link_to "Details", details_path, :class => "btn btn-mini" %></div></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

and my css looks like this:

```
.active {
  background-image:url(/assets/my_arrow.gif);
  background-repeat: repeat-x, no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
.noactive {}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Bootstrap table-striped rule -- `.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td` -- is more specific than your`.active` rule. You could:

- Make the `.active` rule more specific (also, consider making it apply to the `td`, since I seem to remember that working more regularly than styling a `tr`),
- drop `.table-striped` from the table and add your own striping rules, or
- add `!important` if you feel like going nuclear about it.

There's a bunch of resources online about this, for example [Understanding Style Precedence in CSS: Specificity, Inheritance, and the Cascade](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/).

As for striping by hand, yes, it's easy. This is the entire Bootstrap `.table-striped` definition:

```
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td,
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(odd) th {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

Comment: -I don't know what you mean by making the .active rule more specific. I did add add at the td level as shown in second code but the arrow would become chopped off at the edges of the cell and it looked very choppy
-I don't see how to add my own striping rules since the one for .table-striped you copied/pasted is on entire tbody table
-finally I looked up !important and don't understand how it applies to this. Are you suggesting that on the row I need the background image I override the striping with the image? If so that wouldn't work for me as I am trying to have both in one row. Thanks.

Comment: Did you research CSS specificity, for example, by reading the article linked in my response?